# Named arguments from file

Tags: jq

I'd like to have a list of named jq arguments in a file, e.g so that using a file like

```
{ "foo" : "bar", "baz": 123 }
```

Would be equivalent to invoking `jq --argjson foo '"bar"' --argjson baz 123`

Is this possible?

I guess I could use jq to parse the file and emit the arguments part of the CLI, but it feels bad.

In the end I want to run a jq program with several different sets of arguments. E.g.

```
jq -n --argjson foo '"bar"' --argjson baz 123 '"\($foo) is \($baz)"'
jq -n --argjson foo '"RAB"' --argjson baz 321 '"\($foo) is \($baz)"'
```

but each set of arguments taken from separate file instead of specifying them on the command line.

Comment: So you have a JSON object, and want to convert those in to `--argjson`'s to use them in JQ? That sounds like a [x/y issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) since you could just use that original JSON file in JQ.

Comment: That would require changes to the jq program. JQ is invoked several times with the same argument and I want to clean it up without changing the jq program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your set of keys seems to be static, you *could* (whether you also should is on another page, though) prefix your jq filters with a static set of bindings off of the imported arguments object. For example, statically prepend your unchanged jq code once with `$args as {$foo, $baz} |`, and use `--argjson args …` to import the set at once:

```bash
jq -n --argjson args '{"foo": "bar", "baz": 123}' '$args as {$foo, $baz} |'\
'
  "\($foo) is \($baz)"
'
```

```
"bar is 123"
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you could bind more variables with `as`. I guess I could also generate the code fragment based on the json object instead of requiring it to be static

Comment: @JakubBochenski [Just as `{foo}` is a handy way of writing `{foo: .foo}`, so `{$foo}` is a handy way of writing `{foo: $foo}`. Multiple variables may be declared using a single `as` expression by providing a pattern that matches the structure of the input (this is known as "destructuring")](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#variable-symbolic-binding-operator)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list of named jq arguments is in arguments.json,

you can define a shell function as follows :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

jq2(){
    local arguments=$1 args; shift
    mapfile -t args < <(jq -r 'to_entries[] | "--argjson", .key, (.value|@json)' $arguments)
    jq "${args[@]}" "$@"
}

jq2 arguments.json -n '"\($foo) is \($baz)"'
```

Output :

```
"bar is 123"
```

If the value of baz is `"Hello \n\"'$var'\"\t\\ World!"`, containing a lot of special characters, the output is correctly produced :

```
"bar is Hello \n\"'$var'\"\t\\ World!"
```

Comment: don't I need to also escape the inner jq output with @sh?

Comment: @JakubBochenski Adding `@sh` would produce invalid json.

Comment: I mean that `.key, (.value|@json)` should have `| @sh` added in case they containt special characters

Comment: @JakubBochenski Updated answer which proves my original solution handles special characters correctly.